# Looking for way to have a user authenticate against PayPal without losing passport authentication

Tags: node.js, authentication, paypal, passport.js

We are using Passport to authenticate users on our website.  We would like to give our users the ability to link their PayPal account so that if there clients are on the page and they want to make a payment we can direct it to the users PayPal account.

We could have the users just enter their PayPal emails and we could bill to that account but we would like for the user to authenticate to PayPal grant us the rights to get their email and then store that email to allow for future billing.

I can get the user to authenticate against PayPal but in that process I lose the Passport session and so when they are redirected to the website I don't know who they are.

I know that Passport has strategies for PayPal but I am not wanting to authenticate with PayPal to our website.

Does anyone know a way I can authenticate against PayPal while keeping my Passport session?

We are using node.js

Comment: Have you checked out PayPal's [documentation](https://www.paypal.com/merchantapps/appcenter/acceptpayments)?

Comment: @kevintechie I have looked through the docs.  I have it working so that I can pull the email from paypal it is just that I lose my session with the callback from the paypay authentication.  I haven't found anything in the docs that seem to answer this but would be open if someone knows where in the docs that answers this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did figure out how I can move forward.  I had first tried using the generate button way and that seemed a dead end for what I was trying to do.  Then I shifted to the build button and it seemed to have the same problem.  Finally I noticed in the documentation that the example had an additional query parameters called state.  So it seems you can pass this parameter and it will be returned in the request query parameters.  It seems that it has to be called state.  I didn't see anywhere in the documentation that they talk about this but maybe I was just not looking in the right spot.

I will still need to build my session but at least I can know who to build it for.